# How to handle Transport Level Error in C#

Tags: c#

I am stuck with this problem and its my second time that it stopped working and all the work is useless now. I am transferring one million records via tab delimited text file to SQL server 2012 database table. It takes total 3 hours to move this such records because the server is too far away.

Somehow my connection broke with the server and the program processed 600 000 rows and this error comes up and when I fixed the connection error and continue the application it doesn't transfer the records to the database so I have to close the application and try again.

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 – An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

my code below

```
public void bulkinsert_US(string tablename, DataTable dt)
{
    if (con2.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con2.Open();
    }

    SqlBulkCopy blkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con2);
    blkcopy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
    blkcopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
    blkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

    toolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    { toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = blkcopy.BatchSize; }));
    blkcopy.NotifyAfter = 1000;
    blkcopy.SqlRowsCopied +=blkcopy_SqlRowsCopied;

    blkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    blkcopy.Close();

}
```

I'm looking for a handling solution so that I don't have to close the application and start all over again.

Comment: You could transfer your data on batches of 10.000 records at a time so even if it breaks you only lose one batch.

Comment: @Massanu Exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: First, you didn't state the error message, second, you don't have any error handling in your code (this is most likely the cause why your application behaves like it does when something goes wrong)

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Sorry i just edited my question with error.

Comment: @Massanu So if did transfer in batches, it will take longer than it already is? Is there any other way around

Comment: @SohaibAkhtar Where exactly or by which code part is this error message displayed?

Comment: @SohaibAkhtar One could say that in the end it took less time. 4 hours of processing time vs, 3 failed attempts that each took 2 hours.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy When it comes to this line "blkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);"

Comment: @SohaibAkhtar You have not a lot of choices either you break up the batches so you limit the amount of data you loss when connection breaks, or if you can transfer the text file closer to the SQL Server and run the import from there to limit the networking issue